# How do you publish a Xbox Live game on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xbox-live

Curious if any of you have gone through the process? How did you kick it off? Is there anything in particular that we should be aware of when trying to make a Live game?

Comment: Do you mean port/put? I don't think become works. :P However, +1 interesting question.

Comment: As far as I know, you can release a "Windows Phone" game and only pay the $99 "AppHub" fee -- to be "Xbox Live" I believe you need a contract with Microsoft, that said, I've looked around and can't find any documentation on that.

Comment: @Nate, Omnion: Answers to the question should be, well, answers. Not comments.

Comment: @Joe I made it a comment because I don't have a source for what I said, its just my feeling.

Comment: To clarify I am interested in learning how a developer submits a game to the Live library of games. Live is a managed portfolio meaning you have to sign a deal with Microsoft to be a part of it.I was curious if anyone had experience tackling this problem either on the xbox or the phone.

Comment: That your answer is a bad answer is not a reason to make it a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check at this blog post from Andre Vrignaud, he was responsible for windows LIVE strategy.

**From the post:**

> The bar is pretty high for titles to
>   be able to use Xbox LIVE services –
>   we’re aiming for a very high-quality,
>   managed portfolio. But if you feel
>   you’ve got the ideas and the chops to
>   hit that bar, both our publishing
>   partners and ourselves are interested
>   in talking with you!
>
> Feel like you’ve got game? Here’s what
>   you do:
>
> 1. Email wpgames@microsoft.com with a description of your game and your
>      contact information. We’ll send you a
>      content submission form. We love
>      playable demos!
> 2. If your game is accepted, you’ll hear from the developer relations
>      staff and we’ll work with you to get
>      you the resources required to get
>      started.
> 3. We’ll take care of the rest – game integration, promotions, marketing,
>      data analysis and community support.

[It has begun! First sessions on developing games for windows phone at gdc](http://www.ozymandias.com/it-has-begun-first-sessions-on-developing-games-for-windows-phone-at-gdc)

Comment: Thanks this looks like it's close to the answer as I can hope for.

Answer (score 1):

You need a contract with Microsoft. Your should contact them directly (hard) or through one of their partners that work on WP7 (somewhat easier).